# Restrict access to data delivered by pg_featureserv

Tags: postgis

I wan't to use the pg_featureserv service to deliver data from a PostgreSQL/PostGIS database to be displayed in Openlayers. The displayed maps are for internal use only, so the maps are only accessible when users are logged in.

Actually anybody calling the url of the pg_featureserv service directly http://map.mydomain.com:9000/collections/schema.areas/items.json has access to the data.

I wan't to restrict this, so that only the map-pages from the server (the same where the PostgreSQL/PostGIS and the pg_featureserv are runing on) have access to the data. But when I change the HttpHost settings to 127.0.0.1 or to the IP adress of our server, the data isn't displayed anymore in the Openlayers map.

The pg_featureserv.toml looks like this:

```
[Server]
# Accept connections on this subnet (default accepts on all)
# HttpHost = "0.0.0.0"
# HttpHost = "127.0.0.1"

HttpPort = 9000

UrlBase = "127.0.0.1:9000"
```

The requested data is displayed fine inside the Openlayers map.

```
      var areas = new ol.layer.Vector({
         source: new ol.source.Vector({
           url: "http://map.mydomain.com:9000/collections/schema.areas/items",
           format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
         })
      });

      var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
          }),areas
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([6.2, 49.6]),
          zoom: 12
        })
      });
```

Comment: I could add a proxy server inbetween to handle this, something like apache or nginx

Comment: Maybe there is a confusion. With 'internal use' I didn't mean 'Intranet' but the use inside our company which operates from several sites. But maybe I'm missing something? @Timothy: May be You could indicate a more precise example or link how to realize this.

Comment: I was thinking something like in your vhost settings of apache/nginx you set up http://map.mydomain.com and proxy port 80 to 9000 to pg_featureserv and restrict this location, i.e. IP address ranges within your company. This way only users will be able to ask for the data that match this criteria. So somebody using your web app which asks for the data via openlayers will only get a response if the IP range matches.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, to do this you need a proxy server in front of `pg_featureserv`.  Then use IP filtering or some sort of authentication to restrict access to only the users/machines allowed.

Comment: Many thanks for Your help. I'll see how to implement this.